# How do i convert 3d mesh detail into a 2d texture so it reduces load on my pc?

Tags: 3d-view

I have a model with really much detail, but I want to use it in a game without crashing my PC, so I want to convert the 3d detail into a texture which I can then apply to a simplified version of the model. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This is standard practice.  Try search terms such as:  'Blender Normal Baking' I believe Blender Guru's 'Anvil' tutorial covers this quite well for beginners....